# How do you use JS Link with Pages?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, jslink

I'm trying to make a JS Link script that will work with my site's Pages list. Basically I want to display a simple list of page titles. I'm using the Pages Web Part (Web Part > Apps > Pages).

```
var myViews = myViews || {};
myViews.itemHtml = function (ctx) { 
  var returnHtml = "<p>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</p>";
  return ""returnHtml"";
};

(function () {

  var myOverrides = {};
  myOverrides.Templates = {};

  myOverrides.Templates.Header = "<div id='MyCustomView'>";
  myOverrides.Templates.Item = myViews.itemHtml;
  myOverrides.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

  myOverrides.ListTemplateType = 100;
  myOverrides.BaseViewID = 0;

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(myOverrides);

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

The list of corrections/fixes for your script:

1) Replace the line `return ""returnHtml"";` with `return returnHtml;`

2) Make sure the *proper* `ListTemplateType` and `BaseViewID` are specified, in fact those properties are not mandatory and they could be omitted at all. For example, for Pages Library you could specify:

```
myOverrides.ListTemplateType = 850;  //ootb Pages library
myOverrides.BaseViewID = 1;   //default view where Title column is included(!)
```

3) Make sure `Title` column is included in a List View

**Result**

After applying those changes, the customized list view could look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Save below code into a file and upload it into style library (ex: jslinks.js)

   ```
   (function () {
       var overrideCtx = {};
       overrideCtx.Templates = {};
       overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
           "Title": { "View": CustomItem } 
       };
       //  Assign functions or plain html strings to the template set objects:
       //  header, footer and item.
       overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='MyCustomView'>";
       overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

       //  This template is assigned to the CustomItem function.
       overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;

       //  Register the template overrides.
       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
   })();

   /*
    * This function builds the output for the item template.
    * Uses the Context object to access data.
    */
   function CustomItem(ctx) {
       // Build a listitem entry for every in the list.
       var ret = "<p>" + ctx.CurrentItem["FileLeafRef"] + "</p><br/>";
       return ret;
   }
   ```
2. Edit Page -> Edit Webpart Properties -> Miscellaneous -> JS Link

   `~site/style library/jslinks.js`

   `//Change jslinks.js with your filename`
3. Stop editing and refresh the page

Comment: Thanks, how would I get the files's title or name? Did you find some good documentation on this?

Comment: Oh you have to have the Title column enabled (check mark beside display) in the view.